# Why isn't child class able to overwrite `__debugInfo` of parent class?

Tags: php, object, oop, php-carbon

Here's my code:

```
use Carbon\Carbon;

class Demo extends Carbon
{
    public function __debugInfo(): array
    {
        return ['value' => $this->__toString()];
    }
}

$d = new Demo();
print_r($d);
```

What I'd expect as the output is this:

```
Demo Object
(
    [value] => 2023-05-23 13:57:18
)
```

But what I'm getting is this:

```
Demo Object
(
    [endOfTime:protected] =>
    [startOfTime:protected] =>
    [constructedObjectId:protected] => 00000000000000020000000000000000
    [localMonthsOverflow:protected] =>
    [localYearsOverflow:protected] =>
    [localStrictModeEnabled:protected] =>
    [localHumanDiffOptions:protected] =>
    [localToStringFormat:protected] =>
    [localSerializer:protected] =>
    [localMacros:protected] =>
    [localGenericMacros:protected] =>
    [localFormatFunction:protected] =>
    [localTranslator:protected] =>
    [dumpProperties:protected] => Array
        (
            [0] => date
            [1] => timezone_type
            [2] => timezone
        )

    [dumpLocale:protected] =>
    [dumpDateProperties:protected] =>
    [date] => 2023-05-23 13:57:18.314578
    [timezone_type] => 3
    [timezone] => UTC
)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: this is strange...what happens if you take away the return type (remove `: array`)?

Comment: @DerekPollard - same thing.

Comment: try var_dump($d) ?

Comment: `__debugInfo` is only for `var_dump()` (for any object, not just sub-class or Carbon objects)

Comment: @KyleK - how do you explain https://3v4l.org/RCSW8 ?

Comment: I would not rely on it because __debugInfo is mentionned on https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php but not on https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php also https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#language.oop5.magic.debuginfo only talks about var_dump in the description. So print_r might have other rules, need to read the PHP source code to check.